# Django Forms not loading

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have tried numerous things. At one point my forms were loading and now they are't. I get the page to load, but the forms simply don't appear, the page is just my layout.html.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/passreset/$', views.passwordReset, name='passwordReset')
```

**views.py**

```
def passwordReset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return rediect('/account')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'posts/accounts/changepass.html', {'form': form})
```

**changepass.html**

```
{% extends 'posts/layout.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>Change Password</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="containter">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also another question now. I found out it is rendering the page posts/account.html (when I have specified another) why is that?

Comment: Post your layout.html'

Comment: what will by your logic if method `POST` and form not valid?

Comment: it isn't my layout, because my login form shows up. The login form and the register are almost identical i dont understand

Comment: What Bear Brown? That didn't make any sense